# Caching with Symfony depending on user?

Tags: symfony, caching

I am currently working on a website running with Symfony 2.

Some pages are slow, because of heavy MySQL queries (mainly).

I wonder what would be the best way to use cache and increase page load speed ?

One major difficulty is that the content displayed to users may be very different. For instance, one of the slowest page is http://www.avygeo.fr/hotels where each user can see a different list of hotels depending on his friends' reviews.

Thank you for your help

Comment: This is in fact a very broad question. You should start profiling your pages and identifying bottlenecks. Where possible eliminate the bottlenecks. For caching look at HTTP cache. Using Edge-Side Includes can solve some problems where pages are different for each users. Finally there are various ways to cache other things, for example the list of hotels could be calculated on specific intervals and stored in the database to avoid realtime calculation.

Comment: I agree with Gerry... Find your bottlenecks first.  Also implementing a data structure store like Redis will help out. http://redis.io/

Comment: Next to that, also think about the application layer you'd like to cache. In other words, you could simply start caching query results (model), or you could cache Twig blocks (view). This totally depends on the results of your profiling. We eventually for example chose a combination of both.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. I will start with hotels pages since they are the slowest. And before adding new tools like Redis (looks great but above my technical abilities), I will see how to optimize Symfony own tools.